# Overlaying an image on another image using coordinates in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, imagemagick, coordinates, cimg

I'm trying to put first image on a certain area of the second image.

I tried to use imagemagick. I installed it to Visual Studio 2017. I didn't find how to use.

I tried to use CImg ("draw_image" function). I couldn't install properly. Because I couldn't find something how tell me completely.

I want to do this:

**first image:**
https://ibb.co/gTRd3vz

**second image:**
https://ibb.co/bmBYP4S

**for example:**
I want to add the second image in 150x150 coordinate of the first image

like this: (I did with paint, but not what I want. I explain on the result pic)
result pic:
https://ibb.co/0Zh98fW

can someone tell me properly? If there is better solution, I want to know.
I am in a big stuck.

Comment: Can you summarize what your question is?  Are you asking how to install something?  Or how to code something?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your attempt at solving this.

Comment: I couldn’t install these 2 library on Visual Studio. And I couldn’t use them for My purpose. I want to learn both of them @Drew

Comment: @Jesper there is no code. I couldn’t be able  to use

Answer (score 2):

**For implementing an overlay:**

For ImageMagick, specifically [magick++](/questions/tagged/magick%2b%2b), you would use `Magick::Image.composite()` method.

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

int main() {
  Magick::Image first("wizard.png");
  Magick::Image second("rose.png");
  first.composite(second, 150, 150);
  first.write("output.png");
}
```

[image: overlay]

**For using ImageMagick in a Visual Studio VC++ project:**

In project settings, you need to set the include & library directory options to reference the ImageMagick installation location.

See [VC++ Directories Property Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Thank you so much. Also How can I read the images in C:\Images folders? Will I use fopen?

Comment: And is it suitable for real-time video process? I want to take frames and implement them like what you wrote?

Comment: I'm getting LNK2019 unsolved external symbol. I wrote like this: Magick::Image first(c:/wizard.png");

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want and your 150x150 is not clear. Is that the size or offset position. Here is how to make something like what you have for your result using ImageMagick 6 command line. Sorry, I do not know C++ or Magick.Net

1.png

[image]

2.png

[image]

```
convert 1.png -page +650+500 2.png -background white -mosaic result.png
```

[image]

For ImageMagick 7, replace "convert" by "magick".

Comment: How can I use this in Visual Studio 2017? I couldn’t install this library

Comment: And is it suitable for real-time video process? I want to take frames and implement them like what you wrote?

Comment: Also What about the places that “I don’t want this area”?

Comment: I don't know C++ or Visual Studio or Window. See the other answer from emcconville about that. I do not think Imagemagick is a realtime processor, though some functions can be run via GPU. I do not know what you mean by do not want this area. As the second image is shifted partly off the first, the areas that are not on both must be filled in with something. Do you want that something to be transparent?

Comment: can you do this in Visual Studio. Because I'm getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230208/error-unresolved-external-symbol-while-using-magick-library-in-c-in-visual-st

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Visual Studio or Windows. Perhaps you installed the 32-bit version of Visual Studio and need the 64-bit version or the other way around?